# Ruby: Save data with JSON, render data for al users/views/visitors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am saving data with a javascript format, through an action called msg. This works. The new data (message) is loaded/rendered directly in the view, without having to reload the page.

```
def msg
  @message = ProposalMessage.new(message_params)
  @messages = @proposal.proposal_messages

  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to accomplish that the data is refresh for all users, looking at this page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Look into web-sockets. This will take a lot of research on your part. There is no short way of doing this. You can also use Angular js to accomplish this.
You can look in here for a bit of tutorial: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/
And here is a great gem you can use for minimal code. https://github.com/chrismccord/sync

Comment: Thanks! I have come across that topic before and will dive into that. Thanks!